# Multi-Level / IF-statement JOIN in SQL? Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I'll try my best to explain the problem and present examples.

I two tables (Table A and Table B) each of which has three keys available to join on. I want to perform the join on and I want to perform the join in multiple levels. By this, I mean if Key 1 matches between the two tables, then join on that. For the remaining that didn't match, use Key 2 to join, and for the remaining that *still* didn't match, use Key 3 to join. **The hierarchical order of the joins matters.**

Sample Data:

```
        -----------------------------------------------
       | ------ TABLE A ------ | ------ TABLE B ------ |
       | KEY 1 | KEY 2 | KEY 3 | KEY 1 | KEY 2 | KEY 3 |
       |-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
 ROW 1 |  ABC  |  AAA  |  BBB  |  ABC  |  PPP  |  QRS  |
 ROW 2 |  DEF  |  RRR  |  NNN  |  XYZ  |  RRR  |  NMO  |
 ROW 3 |  HIJ  |  TTT  |  NNN  |  GHI  |  MMM  |  QQQ  |
 ROW 4 |  TUV  |  VVV  |  LLL  |  OPQ  |  UUU  |  LLL  |
 ROW 5 |  LMN  |  III  |  EEE  |  XYZ  |  III  |  JJJ  |
 ROW 6 |  PQR  |  CCC  |  OOO  |  WXY  |  HHH  |  DDD  |
        -----------------------------------------------
```

So if I start my join on Key 1, only Row 1 will match and I am done with this step. Then, I move on to Key 2 where Row 2 and Row 5 will match. Finally, I move on to Key 3 and only Row 4 will match.

So I want my final data of Table A and Table B joining to look like:

```
        -----------------------------------------------
       | ------ TABLE A ------ | ------ TABLE B ------ |
       | KEY 1 | KEY 2 | KEY 3 | KEY 1 | KEY 2 | KEY 3 |
       |-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
 ROW 1 |  ABC  |  AAA  |  BBB  |  ABC  |  PPP  |  QRS  | (Key 1)
 ROW 2 |  DEF  |  RRR  |  NNN  |  XYZ  |  RRR  |  NMO  | (Key 2)
 ROW 5 |  LMN  |  III  |  EEE  |  XYZ  |  III  |  JJJ  | (Key 2)
 ROW 4 |  TUV  |  VVV  |  LLL  |  OPQ  |  UUU  |  LLL  | (Key 3)
        -----------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out how to put conditions within SQL's **ON** statement for a join or if I need to do some sort of nested joins.

Thank you so much for your help!

PS: The example tables look like they are sorted in the same order, but that's just for ease of understanding.

Comment: Please show us your table definitions.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: You can use `AND` with `ON` so for instance `LEFT JOIN a ON a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2 != b.key2 AND a.key3 != b.key3` then do this for each key instance. Does that make sense?

Comment: ou say you want to do JOINs in order and you say what the inputs & keys to the later joins are but what relationship does the result bear to these join results? Is it the union of them?.

Comment: mysql or sql-server ? , you have tagged 2 different dbms.

Answer (score 0):

UNION the JOIN ON key1 equal, the JOIN ON key 1 not equal AND key 2 equal, and the JOIN ON key 1 not equal AND key 2 not equal AND key 3 equal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will return the specified result:

```
SELECT a1.key1   AS a_key1
     , a1.key2   AS a_key2
     , a1.key3   AS a_key3
     , b1.key1   AS b_key1
     , b1.key2   AS b_key2
     , b1.key3   AS b_key3
     , '(key 1)' AS `match` 
  FROM tablea a1
  JOIN tableb b1
    ON b1.key1 =  a1.key1

 UNION ALL

SELECT a2.key1
     , a2.key2
     , a2.key3
     , b2.key1
     , b2.key2
     , b2.key3
     , '(key 2)' AS match 
  FROM tablea a2
  JOIN tableb b2
    ON b2.key1 <> a2.key1
   AND b1.key2 =  a2.key2

 UNION ALL

SELECT a3.key1
     , a3.key2
     , a3.key3
     , b3.key1
     , b3.key2
     , b3.key3
     , '(key 3)' AS match 
  FROM tablea a3
  JOIN tableb b3
    ON b3.key1 <> a3.key1
   AND b3.key2 <> a3.key2
   AND b3.key3 =  a3.key3
```